# How to point http traffic to server A and email traffic to server B

Tags: cpanel, amazon-aws, webmail

I have purchased my domain from enom.com hosting from godaddy.com and everything was working perfect today I wanted to deploy our website on a AWS server. I did that and the websites works perfectly but the emails does not delivers. What I did :

Once I downloaded all the files on my AwS server I logged into godaddy control panel and altered the DNS files, before I continue to elaborate this more let me assume IPs of these two servers, the godaddy server has IP 1.1.1.1 and AWS has IP 2.2.2.2 so what I did is made the following changes :

```
Type    name                value
A       @                   2.2.2.2
A       admin               1.1.1.1
A       demo                1.1.1.1
A       mail                1.1.1.1
CNAME   autoconfig          @   
CNAME   autoconfig.admin    @
CNAME   autodiscover        @
CNAME   autodiscover.admin  @
CNAME   cpanel              @
CNAME   email               email.secureserver.net
CNAME   ftp                 @
CNAME   webdisk             @
CNAME   webdisk.admin       @
CNAME   webmail             @
CNAME   whm                 @
CNAME   www                 @
CNAME   www.admin           @
MX      @                   mail.verisiteglobal.com (Priority: 0)
TXT     @                   v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net~all
```

and now my webmail doesn't works

Comment: MX = mail server - change that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to double check the MX record as it appears to be pointing to a different server than your email server although it could simply be a backup system so that if the mail server is offline the verisiteglobal server catches and stores the emails until the serverserver email server is back online.

You say that webmail isn't working but you are point the webmail record to the web root. What you need to have is the email and webmail records as CNAME of email.secureserver.net.